# How to add parameters to Task Groups

Tags: azure-devops

We are creating deployments with TFS 2018.3. If I click on tasks in a deployment and create a Task Group out if it, it recognizes the used parameters but if I change parameter usage in an already existing Task Group, or edit the newly create group, parameter changes are not applied to the parameter list in the group.

Comment: The only working way I found is to export, edit json file (add to input array) and import it again.